# Как установить MySQL на FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

Получил задание настроить самый простой почтовый сервер на FreeBSD. Столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу установить базу данных MySQL. Подскажите, может кто знает откуда ее вытащить?

[image: FreeBSD10.4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pkg install mysql57-server mysql57-client`

Или используйте альтернативный вариант:

`portmaster databases/mysql57-server databases/mysql57-client`

А теперь к сути вопроса:

1) Такого каталога (как вам сказала система) -- нет.

2) Логично было бы грепнуть, и посмотреть что есть в каталоге /usr/ports/databases по ключевому слову "mysql".

3) Исходя из этого идти к намеченной цели.

4) Если необходимо именно mysql51- идите в гугл.

Comment: Использовал альтернативный вариант - пошла установка. Спасибо.
Подскажите, как посмотреть, что есть в каталоге?
Сам каталог /databases есть, с этим разобрался.

Просто я со всем новичок, ничего не знаю практически.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вы сейчас в каталоге /databases - то ls

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Тогда поставьте галочку, если не трудно.